# How to do the reversed eight queens problem (if a pair hit each other) P2

Tags: python, coordinates, n-queens

It is possible to place 8 queens on an 8×8 chessboard so that no two queens threaten each other. Thus, it requires that no two queens share the same row, column, or diagonal.

Given a placement of 8 queens on the chessboard. If there is a pair of queens that violates this rule, print YES, otherwise print NO. The input consists of eight coordinate pairs, one pair per line, with each pair giving the position of a queen on a standard chessboard with rows and columns numbered from 1 to 8.

here's my code

```
def get_coords():
    x, y = input().split()
    x = int(x)
    y = int(y)
    return x, y
a, b = get_coords()
c, d = get_coords()
e, f = get_coords()
g, h = get_coords()
i, j = get_coords()
k, l = get_coords()
m, n = get_coords()
o, p = get_coords()
#check cross or straight
if a==c or c==e or e==g or g==i or i==k or k==m or m==o or o==a or b==d or d==f or f==h or h==j or j==l or l==n or n==p or p==b:
    print("YES")
#check diagonally
elif a==b and c==d or c==d and e==f or e==f and g==h or g==h and i==j or i==j and k==l or k==l and a==b:
    print("YES")
elif abs(a-b)==abs(c-d) or abs(c-d)==abs(e-f) or abs(e-f)==abs(g-h) or abs(g-h)==abs(i-j) or abs(i-j) == abs(k-l) or abs(k-l)==abs(a-b):
    print("YES")
else:
    print("NO")
```

example coordination

```
1 3
2 1
3 2
4 3
5 4
6 6
7 8
8 5
```

outcome

```
No
```

Comment: But what is your question?

Comment: Given a placement of 8 queens on the chessboard. If there is a pair of queens that violates this rule, print YES, otherwise print NO. The input consists of eight coordinate pairs, one pair per line, with each pair giving the position of a queen on a standard chessboard with rows and columns numbered from 1 to 8.

Comment: @Meno That's not a question, that's a program specification. What answer do you want from us? Is your code not working? Are you asking for a better way of doing this? Something else?

Answer (score 0):

Below code may help.

```py
class queen:
  def __init__(self,x,y):
    self.x=int(x)
    self.y=int(y)
  def is_horizontal_threat(self,new_queen):
    if self.x==new_queen.x:
      return True
    return False
  def is_vertical_threat(self,new_queen):
    if self.y==new_queen.y:
      return True
    return False
  def is_diagonal_threat(self,new_queen):
    if abs(self.x-new_queen.x)/abs(self.y-new_queen.y)==1:
      return True
    return False
  def is_threat(self,new_queen):
    if self.is_horizontal_threat(new_queen) or self.is_vertical_threat(new_queen) or self.is_diagonal_threat(new_queen):
      return True
    return False

def get_queen():
    x, y = input().split()
    return queen(x, y)

def check_queens():
  queens=[]
  for _ in range(8):
    new_queen=get_queen()
    for queen in queens:
      if queen.is_threat(new_queen):
        return "YES"
    queens.append(new_queen)
  return "NO"

print(check_queens())
```

Output:

```
1 3
2 1
3 2
YES
```